# Get full stack trace out of grails run-script in grails project

Tags: grails, stack-trace, verbose

I run grails run-script   and I get a stacktrace that is 78-deep or more. It only shows part of it.For example:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:369)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultJavaExecAction.execute(DefaultJavaExecAction.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.exec(JavaExec.java:74)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:141)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:123)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:632)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:615)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:76)
    ... 78 more
```

I need to see what's in the "... 78 more"

So I tried

```
grails run-script --stacktrace <pathToGroovyScript> <commandLineArgument>
```

and I get a stacktrace with:

```
(NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
```

So I add

```
grails run-script --stacktrace --verbose <pathToGroovyScript> <commandLineArgument>
```

and

```
grails run-script --verbose <pathToGroovyScript> <commandLineArgument>
```

and I stil get a shortened stack trace but this time the instruction to use --verbose is not there.

It seems this functionality is broken.

**Troubleshooting info**

```
grails --version
| Grails Version: 3.3.0
| Groovy Version: 2.4.11
| JVM Version: 1.8.0_121
```

application.properties:

```
grailsVersion=3.2.6
gradleWrapperVersion=3.0
```